Каким членом предложения является пояснительный член?

Конференция состоится в то же время, то есть в 13.00!

1.В то же время (какое) - в 13.00 [приложение] (определение)?
2.В то же время (когда) - в 13.00 [когда] (обстоятельство)?
Какой вариант правильный?

Конференция состоится (когда?) в то же время, то есть в 13.00!
Розенталь:

Слова, поясняющие смысл предшествующего члена предложения, выделяются (или отделяются) знаками препинания (запятыми, тире, двоеточием). Различие между уточняющими и пояснительными членами предложения заключается в том, что если уточнение — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому [см. § 22], то пояснение — это обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами.
Перед пояснительным членом предложения обычно стоят слова именно, а именно, то есть.

Предшествующий член в данном случае — это обстоятельство времени, выраженное падежной формой существительного. Пояснение также будет являться обстоятельством.
